# Meta tag og:title inside Facebook Application is ignored

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook Application with an iframe based canvas that contains a like button (also iframe), in the head of my iframe i've specified the standard meta tags (og:title, og:url, og:site_name) and they seem to work fine (the information is displayed correctly in the profile wall) except for the title. 
I've tested various links of the app with the Facebook URL Linter and the ug:title tag is ignored completly.

Have any of you had any trouble with the open graph tags inside facebook applications?

Any ideeas are apreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried every possible combination and suggestion in adding og meta tags to my page, but none of them worked. When testing URL with facebook URL Linter it always returned default values defined on application admin page. Like it doesn't see og meta tags. And what was more interesting is that when I look the page source, og meta tags existed but haven't been evaluated by facebook or linter.

Now, in my canvas page I defined login/authentication (and depending redirection etc) at the top, before html and og meta tags definition, and that was the main problem.

> If you perform FB login redirection/authentication before providing og meta tags,
>   then FB crawlers/linter will not be able to detect your meta info and will try to auto-fill it.

Comment: Could you add the essence of the link to your answer? We want to build a resource here that stays even if links will go bad.

Comment: @aleksandar, i ended up using the same "hack", i'm not calling it a solution :)

Comment: @Paŭlo, ok I'll copy same content as on other post.

Comment: @Militaru, I'm not sure if we can call it a 'hack' if it's strictly required by facebook or Linter. It's more the issue with facebook documentation that's missing some of the important guidelines (I think we have experienced that many times :)  Anyway, I think it should be part of facebook documentation as proper way of defining Open Graph protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem in my app http://apps.facebook.com/tripline  It seems that Facebook doesn't process links to pages inside apps the same way as pages they hit directly.

You can see the difference in the URL Linter:

1. The og:url on the canvas page: http://apps.facebook.com/tripline/trip.php?id=2015071615051003BEE6FBED6F531103 (og:title is ignored, get trip.php instead)
2. The url to the actual page loaded in the iframe: http://www.tripline.net/api/fbcanvas/trip.php?id=2015071615051003BEE6FBED6F531103#frame-top (og:title correct, but can't link to this because it's not in the frame)
3. The page on the main site: http://www.tripline.net/trip/The_Boston_Freedom_Trail-2015071615051003BEE6FBED6F531103  (og:title correct, if i can't figure things out, i'm just going to set the og:url on the canvas page to this)

Not really an answer, but at least you know you're not alone or crazy...which is worth something.

Comment: Thanks Byron, maybe somebody will find a fix for this issue.

Comment: By the way, setting the og:url on the page doesn't correct the problem becuase the like button and fbml share button send the actual url of the page, not the og:url  so, like buttons will continue to be broken and we've changed the share button from the old fbml share to the newer javascript-based FB.ui share dialog where we can completely control the URL passed.